# Bind StackPanel to method that adds child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows

Here's my issue: I have a wrapper class that contains sets of lists that contain 15 images each. I want to bind a central `StackPanel` to a method that actually ***modifies*** the same `StackPanel` that was passed to it and adds child `StackPanel` elements that contain 15 images each.

To clarify:

- I have a central `StackPanel` that has a vertical orientation. ***This `StackPanel` is located inside of a `DataTemplate`!***.

  ```
  <DataTemplate>
       <Grid x:Name="ImageDisplayGrid" Height="861" Width="656">
            <StackPanel x:Name="CentralImagePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="841" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="636"/>
       </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- I have many instances of my wrapper class that contain up to 15 images each (as `WritableBitmap` objects.
- I want to bind my central `StackPanel` to some method that will modify that `StackPanel`, iterating through my list of wrapper classes and adding child `StackPanel` controls to the central `StackPanel` for each instance of my wrapper class found.
- For each instance of the (ImageSet1, ImageSet2, etc for example) wrapper class, the new `StackPanel` that will be added to the central `StackPanel` will be populated using the images contained in that wrapper class instance.
- In my mind there isn't really anything to be 'returned' here, so I was hoping there was a way to just pass the control (the central `StackPanel`) to some method, let the method modify it, and then carry on after the central `StackPanel` is populated  with its child `StackPanels'.

To clarify even more:

Think of NetFlix. You know how you can scroll vertically through each category and each category allows you to scroll  horizontally? Thats what I am trying to emulate, only I want it to be dynamic and bound to my wrapper class that contains a list of Images to use.

My main obstacle right now is that the central `StackPanel` is located within a `DataTemplate`, so there isn't an easy way to access it during runtime. On top of that it would be nicer to use a binding anyway.

I have tried to use `IValueConverter` to turn my wrapper class into a list of `StackPanel` objects that the central `StackPanel` can use, but that didn't work. I've also searched for ways to bind a control to a method that has no return property without any luck as well.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about this wrong. Really, really, wrong. `StackPanel` is a *layout* control. You shouldn't *ever* be directly modifying its children or any other properties.

As you've noticed, there is no real way to do this task in the way you describe.

To display collections, use an `ItemsControl`. In your case, it would be something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource={"Binding Videos"}>
               <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                      <!-- Whatever -->
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Notice the inner template is **another** `ItemsControl`, this time with a horizontal `StackPanel` as the panel template.

Comment: This is the correct WPF way to do it. Build your data objects first and make sure you get them correct, then build/bind your UI to data in order to provide a user-friendly interface so users can interact with them.To use the Netflix example, your data would have a collection of CategoryModel objects, and each CategoryModel object would have a Videos collection. An ICommand can be used to add/modify these data collections. A UI such as the XAML provided here would be used to provide a user-friendly interface for displaying the objects, and a button would be used to execute command to modify